# Check file_get_contents return before printing it

Tags: php, mysql, json, web-services, php-7

So I'm in an enviroment where i cannot use `curl` so after some research I found that i can use `file_get_contents` with a `stream_context_create` context.

It works great, however I noticed that if the request fails `file_get_contents` returns false, and I wanted to print a JSON object indicating the error instead of plain `false`.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
$postdata = http_build_query(
    $_POST
);

$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

echo file_get_contents($urlAtividade, false, $context);
```

I use this to get data from another WEBService. My concern here is that some requests have really big outputs, so I'm wondering about what's the best way to check this.

I would like to know if I save the return in a variable, would the `file_get_contents` return be doubled in memory? Because my biggest concern here is creating overhead or running out of memory.

```
$return = file_get_contents($urlAtividade, false, $context);

if($return === FALSE){
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Request Failed";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
else {
    echo $return;
}
```

I was wondering if there is a way to print the result and return false inside the `if` statement?

Comment: if you create a function then you can return a true false and echo/print_r resault..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to worry about this.

Assigning a value to a variable doesn't make a copy of it, it just creates a reference to the same memory. Copies are only made if you modify one of them.

If you want to avoid copying the contents into memory, you would have to use `readfile()` rather than `file_get_contents()`. This copies the contents directly into the PHP output buffer, which is flushed periodically when it gets full (unless you've turned on output buffering so you can capture it). But if you do this then you won't be able to check the value first.

Comment: I really don't need the contents on script, I just need to flush it to the client. so using `readfile()` will be perfect for my needs because if i get FALSE then i can print the error JSON object. thanks.